# No route to host errorno 113 openstack

Tags: routes, ip, openstack, host, cloudify

I'm having trouble getting an IP address for a UI. Here is the error message I got when trying to set the IP address:

> Attempting to connect...
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.227.124.50', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3.1/status (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',))

There is also the other UI which was set up by OpenStack I can't access that too, I used a foxy proxy and still can access it, do I need to create some flow rules to make it accessible?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like port 80 egress is not open somewhere in the route between your local machine and the world.

I suggest to check that all security groups, firewalls, iptables and of course your proxy, enable connection to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with library urllib3. The ip address was incorrect, so check if your ip address is correct.